# Traefik and Django on a Subpath

Tags: django, reverse-proxy, traefik

Following setup I want to achieve inside Docker with Traefik and Django:

- http://domain/app1
- http://domain/app2

My `docker-compose.yml` contains the following labels for the containers:

- `` traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=Host(`my.host.de`) && PathPrefix(`/app1`) ``
- `traefik.http.routers.app1.middlewares=app1`
- `traefik.http.middlewares.app1.headers.customresponseheaders.SCRIPT_NAME=/app1`

I did the same for `app2`.

In the `settings.py` of both apps I set: `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = env('FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME', default=None)` which then should get resolved via the ENV File where I have `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME=/app1`.

On Django side I always get a 404 with the message that this path does not exist and I should choose from an existing one.

Django recognizes the URL as `http://my.host.de/app1` and tells me `The current path, app1, didn't match any of these.`

EDIT: Since my setup is thought to be both for dev and prod envs, I am using the Django built in server as well as Gunicorn for Running the Django apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a `SCRIPT_NAME` header to django, you have to use `customrequestheaders` instead of `customresponseheaders` when creating the middleware